# Backup Script to copy only latest file per filetype from folder

Tags: powershell, copy

I need a script to copy a set of filetypes (but just the most recent (Backup) file!) from a backup structure and delete older existing files in the destination.

This is what I got, but I am stuck in the last 2 commands (del and the copy command) :

```
# Define Source
$Source = "D:\Fullbackups"
$Destination = "X:"

# Array to filter Types
$Filetype = @("*.vbk", "*.vbm", "*.bco")

# Loop through each Subfolder
foreach ($Folder in Get-ChildItem $Source -Directory) {

# Get latest File per Filetype
  foreach ($fType in $Filetype) {

  # del existing $fType in Destination, so older backups do not waste space
  del $Destination\$Folder\*.$fType

get-childitem -path $Folder.FullName -Filter $fType | 
    where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | 
        sort-object -Property $_.CreationTime | 
            select-object -last 1 | 
                copy-item -Destination (join-path $Destination\$Folder $_)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you forgot to add the errors you have been getting, or at least what exactly happens\not happens.

That said: There are a few errors in your code.

A Best Practice but still helpful to avoid issues hard to correct: never use aliases in your scripts. They are fine for quick&dirty writing on the terminal, but in scrips the risk of errors, or just causing confusion, is too great.
So: No `del` and use `Remove-Item` instead.

The `.PsIsContainer` property just makes sure it's a file and not a directory: you can obtain the same result in a much more efficient way by adding the `-File` flag to `Get-ChildItem` instead of using `Where-Object`

`Sort-Object -Property` uses only the name of the property, not the reference to the current item(`$_`)

`Join-Path` requires either strings or string arrays: `$Destination\$Folder` is neither. You'd need to use `"$Destination\$Folder"` instead, but at that point just let `Join-Path` bother with it. Plus: `$Folder` would have as value the ENTIRE path: you need to use `$Folder.BaseName`

have some code on me(make sure to double check everything of course):

```
# Define Source
$Source = 'D:\Fullbackups'
$DestinationBase = 'X:'

# Array to filter Types
$Filetype = @('*.vbk', '*.vbm', '*.bco')

# Loop through each Subfolder
foreach ($Folder in (Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Directory)) {

    # Set the destination path for the iteration
    # let Join-Path bother with joining them correctly
    $DestinationFinal = Join-Path -Path $DestinationBase -ChildPath $Folder.Name
    
    # Get latest File per Filetype
    foreach ($fType in $Filetype) {


        # delete existing $Dateityp , so older backups do not waste spaceremo
        Get-ChildItem -Path $DestinationFinal -Filter $fType | 
            Remove-Item

        # get all _FILES_ from $Ordner.FullName that match the $Dateityp
        Get-ChildItem -Path $Ordner.FullName -File -Filter $Dateityp | 
            # sort them by creation time.
            Sort-Object -Property CreationTime | 
            # Select only the first one=the most recent
            Select-Object -Last 1 | 
            # copy it to the destination
            Copy-Item -Destination $DestinationFinal
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, I did not write error codes.
The "del" line is untested, since I was unsure and the last command was working if I replaced the Copy-item ... with just write-host
So I assumed it should work, but i did not get the full name.
Sorry, I was just confused and could not go on, since I do not code often

Comment: a lot(most?) of powershell cmdlets have the `-WhatIf` flag you can use to see if they are working correctly without actually enact their function, ie: see if `Remove-item` works correctly(at least formally) but without actually deleting anything

Comment: thanks. I knew about the -WhatIf flag, but zero experience in using it for real. and currently I need some working functions for the backup environment, therefore I asked for help...